# Difference between stock_move and stock_picking on Odoo(Openerp)?

Tags: module, odoo, stock

can anyone please tell me what's the difference between stock_move & stock_picking? If stock_move trace all movements of products from a location to another why using stock_picking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stock_picking is simply a collection of stock_move. Normally, when a stock_picking is created, it includes many items in it and each line in the picking is a stock move. A stock_picking is done only when all stock_moves in that picking are done. Same concept as sale_order and sale_order_line

Comment: Thank you @thangtn, by the way i'm looking for a good odoo(openerp) documentation or developper tutorial if you have some information :)

Comment: So far I learn from Odoo Development Essentials book and Odoo official site. If you just start Odoo, then I recommend you to read Odoo Development Essentials first. I believe Packt just released a new edition for Odoo 10

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)

Comment: `Same concept as sale_order and sale_order_line` If so then what is the relationship between `stock_move` and `stock_move_line`?