# What is the difference between stock.pack.operation and stock.move in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Can any one explain difference between stock.pack.operation and stock.move that created in every picking order in odoo ?
and why create stock.pack.operation from stock.quant instead of stock.move in picking order?
thanks.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068060/difference-between-stock-move-and-stock-picking-on-odooopenerp?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Odoo stock move is a higher level operation and it breaks down to one or multiple pack.operations. You can think moves as a batch request to move products between locations, and pack.operations as a set of more detailed operations to fulfill the whole move request. A move can for example request for 5 items of a product and it is broken down to 5 pack.operations fulfilling pointing to exact products with serial numbers and a certain warehouse location.

In newer Odoo version 12 the pack.operation has been renamed to stock.move.line. This naming will make it more obvious that a move contains of one or multiple move.lines (=pack.operations).

Answer (score 0):

The model stock.move.operation.link is connected with stock.move and stock.pack.operation respectively. The One2many link exist in both stock.move and stock.pack.operation towards stock.move.operation.link